# JavaScript error, even though I am not running any jsp files

Tags: php, javascript, debugging, jsp, google-chrome

Google chrome's console box shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
```

The files I'm using are .php, .js, and .css. Currently, I'm not using any JSPs.

What is calling the `sf_main.jsp` file?  I don't see any JSP imports even in my header files.

Comment: jquery plugin for dropdown, http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Comment: That's a JavaScript error, not a JSP error. It's impossible to get a JSP error from your browser. The string "jsp" does not appear in the error you posted.

Comment: then why does the file sf_main.jsp show up in my error console...

Comment: this will help, http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1979591&start=75

Comment: And this also, http://technologydribble.info/tag/google-chrome/

Comment: holy shiit that fastsave removal did the trick, thank you god!!